# How to make patent family graph?

Tags: prior-art

How to find total patent family for a given topic per year? Please provide answer with example.

Comment: Could you please add some details to your question? It isn’t clear to me what you are asking for.

Comment: Perhaps you are asking about patent maps? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent_map

Comment: Maybe this wikipedia page? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent_visualisation

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for, but I would recommend you look at [The Lens](https://www.lens.org). The Lens provides some automatic charting of results, and you can easily limit the searches by date, CPC classifications, and other criteria. Depending on what you are searching for, you get a range of chart options.You can also export the search results for analysis using other programs. Here is an example.

[image]